Добавочное обстоятельственное значение оборота?
Правильно ли я понимаю, что в большинстве случаев вопрос о наличии в составе причастного оборота добавочного значения принимает автор:

Умирающий от истощения воробушек выпил почти всю лужу. (ПО показан только как распространитель подлежащего)
Умирающий от истощения, воробушек выпил почти всю лужу.

(выпил, потому что умирал от жажды, добавочное значение обстоятельства на первом плане)

В первом как бы известно, что воробушек умирает от истощения и утверждается только то, что он выпил лужу. Во втором же фактически делается два утверждения-предложения. Воробушек умирает и он выпил лужу. Это не автор принимает, это логика - что уже известно, а что утверждается.

Для подобных выводов нужно работать с примерами, взятыми из литературы, а приведенное предложение таким не выглядит, а выглядит несколько неестественно. Можно, конечно, и придумать, но тогда вместе с  контекстом. Итак, семантика, структура предложения, контекст – вот что влияет на решение задач. А что же автор, совсем бесправный? Нет, отчего же, автор свободен в своих решениях, когда  строит текст, подбирает грамматическую структуру предложения, чтобы выразить нужный смысл. Думаю,  в этом случае решение зависит именно от структуры, даже причинная семантика не так важна.
